# Title updates differently than Graphics

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've been working on a simple program to input a list of times and show how many hours, minutes, and seconds are left until then.  I'm having a delay issue where the JFrame is not being update at the same time as the title.

picture: http://i.imgur.com/se08bXm.png

Here is my source code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Schedule extends JFrame {

public String out = "";


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    new Schedule();
}

public Schedule() throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    setSize(300, 60);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("schedule"));

    ArrayList<Calendar> list = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        Calendar then = new GregorianCalendar();
        then.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, in.nextInt());
        then.set(Calendar.MINUTE, in.nextInt());
        then.set(Calendar.SECOND, in.nextInt());
        list.add(then);
        list2.add(in.nextLine());
    }

    while(true) {
        now = new GregorianCalendar();
        int i = 0;
        for (Calendar c : list) {
            if (c.compareTo(now) > 0) {
                out = (difference(now, c) + list2.get(i));
                setTitle(out);
                long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() - t < 1000);
                repaint();
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

private String difference(Calendar now, Calendar then) {
    String out = "";
    int seconds = (int) ((then.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000);
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    int hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes %= 60;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 60);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.setFont(new Font("", 0, 32));
    g.drawString(out, 5, 50);
}
```

}

How can I fix my code so that the JFrame updates at the same time as the title?
I've tried removing the 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - t < 1);
so that it updates constantly, but that just makes the text flash very fast.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: This looks like a prime example where you should be using a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Busy looping is not a good idea. You are also breaking the swing [threading rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Also, don't override paint()!!! This is NOT the way custom painting is done when using Swing. Check out the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting`. You will find the tutorial by displaying the Table of Contents from the link given to you above. I suggest you read through most of the tutorial for Swing basics.

Comment: Instead of overriding `paint`, you should override `paintComponent`.